# A rigid rotating rod that breaks in two pieces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose we have a rigid rod of lenght $L$ and homegenous mass density. One of its extreme points, say $P$, is fixed so that the rod can rotate around the axis passing in it.

Initially the rod is held horizontally, then it is left and when it reaches the vertical position it breaks, without generating any impulsive force, in two equal pieces.

I'm wondering about how to find the angular velocity of the two fragments immediately after the rod breaks.

I tried but without succes, here is what I did.

I suppose that energy is conserved, that is:

$$
E_{rod}= E_{1} + E_{2}
$$ 
where $1$ labels the upper fragment and $2$ the lower fragment of the rod.

We have:

$$
E_{rod}=\frac{1}{2}I_{rod}\omega_{rod}^{2}
$$
$$
E_{1}= \frac{1}{2}I_{1}\omega_{1}^{2}
$$
$$
E_{2}=\frac{1}{2}I_{2}\omega_{2}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{m}{2}V^{2}_{2}
$$
where $V_{2}$ is the velocity of the center of mass of the lower fragment and the moment of inertia with respect to P are:

$$
I_{rod}=\frac{mL^{2}}{3}
$$
$$
I_{1}=\frac{mL^{2}}{24}
$$
$$
I_{2}=\frac{7mL^{2}}{24}
$$

**EDIT**

According to V.Moretti's comments we know that energy and angular momentum are conserved, thus we have the system:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{c} E_{rod}= E_{1} + E_{2} \\ \vec{L}_{rod}=\vec{L}_{1} + \vec{L}_{2}\end{array}\right.
$$

I think it is:

$$
\vec{L}_{tot}=I_{rod}\vec{\omega}_{rod}
$$
$$
\vec{L}_{1}=I_{1}\vec{\omega}_{1}
$$
$$
\vec{L}_{2}=I_{2}\vec{\omega}_{2} + \frac{m}{2}\vec{r}\wedge\vec{V}_{2}
$$

Moreover I think that $\vec{V}_{2}$ can be simply calculated considering the center of mass of the lower fragment as a point of the rod and then use the well-known relation between angular velocity and velocity:

$$
\vec{V}_{2}=\vec{\omega}_{rod}\wedge \vec{r}
$$
and thus, in a right-handed coordinate system with the z-axis exiting the screen, it is:

$$
\vec{V}_{2}=(-\omega_{rod}\hat{z})\wedge(-\frac{3}{4}L\hat{y})=-\frac{3}{4}L\omega_{rod}\hat{x}
$$
and:

$$
\vec{r}\wedge\vec{V}_{2}=(-\frac{3}{4}L\hat{y})\wedge(-\frac{3}{4}L\omega_{rod}\hat{x})=-\frac{9}{16}L^{2}\omega_{rod}\hat{z}
$$

Now there is nothing that indicates motion in the x-z and y-z planes, thus the conservation of the angular momentum should be a scalar equation, namely:

$$
L_{tot}=I_{rod}\omega_{rod}=I_{1}\omega_{1} + I_{2}\omega_{2} + \frac{m}{2}\vec{r}\wedge\vec{V}_{2}=
$$
$$
=I_{1}\omega_{1} + I_{2}\omega_{2} -\frac{9}{32}mL^{2}\omega_{rod}=L_{1} + L_{2}
$$

Now I am trying to solve the system:

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{2}I_{rod}\omega_{rod}^{2}= \frac{1}{2}I_{1}\omega_{1}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}I_{2}\omega_{2}^{2} + \frac{9mL^{2}\omega_{rod}^{2}}{64}\\ I_{rod}\omega_{rod}=I_{1}\omega_{1} + I_{2}\omega_{2} -\frac{9}{32}mL^{2}\omega_{rod}\end{array}\right.
$$
but, quite surprisingly, I am not having good results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, but you could try to follow this way. Immediately after the rod $PQ$ breaks into $PQ_1$ and $Q_2Q$ the two points $Q_1,Q_2$ have the same velocity as there is no explosion (impulsive force). Moreover the total angular momentum with respect to the fixed point $P$ is conserved and the total energy is conserved too (provided no friction forces/momenta act in $P$). I think this is enough to solve the problem, as the unknowns are the two omegas and the velocity of the centre of mass of the unconstrained piece of rod.

Comment: @V.Moretti Thank You for the reply. I have a little doubt because I am not sure of the conservation of the angular momentum, indeed there is the force of gravity which acts upon the two fragments, ad thus there should be its torque. However if we consider the breaking situation "as" an elastic collision, the torque of the force of gravity is negligible. Is this right?

Comment: Actually I was thinking the process in the absence of gravitational force. However, the torque of gravitational force is negligible (as the force is vertical) just during the short lapse of time $\Delta t\to 0$ of the breaking of the rod.  It should be neglected and it is safe to assume that the total angular momentum is conserved **just during**  that $\Delta t$ (but not **before** and **after**).

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought, but what do you mean whit "the torque of gravitational force is negligible (as the force is vertical)..."? I think it is negligible because gravity is not an impulsive force. I do not understand how the fact that gravity "is vertical" relates to it.

Comment: $\vec{x} \times \vec{g}=\vec{0}$ where $\vec{x}$ is along the rod (starting form $P$) in vertical situation. So $\frac{d \vec{L}_{P,tot}}{dt}= \vec{0}$ at the considered instant. However you are right: The gravitational force is not impulsive so that you can neglect it anyway.

Comment: Thank You, I have been idle, otherwise I would not have you bored with that question (I was trying to understand Marsden's differential geometric approach to the rigid body and so I did not see the fact that the wedge product of parallel vector is null). Thanks again for your disponibility.